# Flutter : Can't launch project though it worked perfectly a few minutes ago

Tags: gradle, flutter

So I was working on a flutter project and everything was fine, it ran perfectly on my device but there was a shortage and my computer rebooted, since then the project won't run.

Here's the error message:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.

  > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
  >   java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Amane Hosanna\Desktop_\FLUTTER\complete guide\budgetizer\build\app\intermediates\signing_config\debug\out\signing-config.json (Acces Denied)
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 34sGradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ci4l.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the CLI of this project and run: `flutter clean`

This command line will clean all the corrupted files and may solve your problem!